# What are the differences among all top level domain?

Tags: networking, dns, domain

I knew that top level domain are installed for every root dns server in the world. But as we know, many .com TLD used for non-commercial but .edu is used for educational purpose. Can we register a domain name about sport but with .gov TLD? Or any advantages and disadvantages for every top level domain?

Comment: This is not really appropriate here. You should not be using .gov for anything not related to the (us)/government + so sport would for the most part be inappropriate here. .Org might be more appropriate. Different TLDs have different rules - you would need to read the applicable ones. Note there are also cctld's which can be another grey area (for example .me)

Comment: Thank You.... :)